# How to convert Directory content URI (treeUri) to absolute path

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to pickup directory in react native and using `react-native-document-picker` library, But the path I receive starts with `content://` which I won't be able to use in my program.

I found many solutions to convert content path to a normal path but they didn't work for `treeUri`.

How can I convert a path like `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments` to `/storage/emulated/0/Documents`

Comment: "which I won't be able to use in my program" -- why not? "I found many solutions to convert content path to a normal path but they didn't work for treeUri" -- they do not work reliably for any `Uri`. There is no requirement for a document tree to represent a directory on the filesystem. Even if it does, there is no guaranteed way to identify what that directory is. Also, bear in mind that your app does not have access to `Documents/` via filesystem APIs, for documents created by other apps, on Android 11+.

Comment: @CommonsWare The other libraries that I use like `react-native-fs` doesn't support that and it only works with absolute path.

Comment: @jasmine try this library, it worked well for one of my project. https://github.com/Wraptime/react-native-get-real-path

Comment: Then find other libraries that work properly with `Uri` values. Or, create your own such libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your comment, The library you sent didn't work for directory uri and nor other native java codes so I ended up using `expo-file-system` that works like `react-native-fs` but also supports uri path

Comment: @jasmine so you got it working?